# copy whole folder to another location using msbuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

There is any way where we can copy foler from one location to another.My folder containg window installer package and setup appliction.so i want copy these item to anoter folder.
i dont want to use below code

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(PublishFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PublishFiles->'$(FilesToDelete)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
```

Answer (score 1):

That Copy task has a DestinationFolder attribute you may use in lieu of the DestinationFiles attribute.

```
<Copy SourceFiles="c:\myfolder\**\*.*" DestinationFolder="c:\mydestination\" />
```